# MVC 3 Razor - Drop down list within Html list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've got a list of objects that have a Name and a list of values and another property representing the SelectedValue.

I wanted to display the Name and then have a drop down - but not sure how to do it!

Can anyone assist please?

With the following example p.Name works, its the p.Values and p.SelectedValues bits that don't!

```
<div id="gridProps">
    <ul id="props">
    @foreach (var p in Model.AvailableProperties)
    {
        <li>@p.Name : @Html.DropDownListFor(p.SelectedValue, p.Values)</li>
    }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Whant does "doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `@Html.DropDownList` instead of `@Html.DropDownListFor`

`@Html.DropDownList` actually has the overload that you're looking for:

```
@Html.DropDownList(string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList)
```

All of the `@Html.DropDownListFor` overloads take an `Expression<Func<...>>` as the first parameter, and it doesn't look like that's what you're passing in your call.